# Is there any delegate method of SKStoreReviewController?

Tags: ios, storekit, skstorereviewcontroller

I am using `SKStoreReviewController` to get rating of app from the user so I need `SKStoreReviewController` delegate methods to track the user activity means what the user press from the popup "cancel" or "Submit".

Comment: Might answer your question :https://medium.com/@kavithakumarasamy89/skstorereviewcontroller-apple-way-to-request-review-and-rating-inside-ios-app-in-ios-10-3-453a6f897e9d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SKStoreReviewController` does not have a delegate. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller